# Filter on list of string values in column using pandas df.query()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a dataframe in which column having list of values. I want to filter on multiple conditions. How can I do that?

```
>>> my_df
        col   values
0         c1  [1,2,3]
1         c2  ['a', 'b', 'c']
2         c3  [11,12,13]


>>> my_df.query(df.query(" `c2` in '['a','b','c']' "))
```

I expect the output to be

```
       col   values
1         c2  ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: my_df represents a DataFrame which consits of lists of distinct values? And you want to filter for exact match? Why do you want to use 'in' at all?

Comment: @Jan Even i tried using ==. Still i'm not getting expected output

Comment: Interesting behaviour. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Indeed @Jan : at 1st I thought this question was a no-brainer, then I discovered it had unsuspected depths! I found this interesting article on the subject: https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-list-values-in-pandas-dataframes-a177e534f173

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the lists to `tuple`

```
print(my_df[my_df['values'].apply(tuple) == ('a', 'b', 'c')])
```

To use `query` change `values` column to `tuple` first

```
my_df['values'] = my_df['values'].apply(tuple)
t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
print(my_df.query('values == @t'))
```

Output:

```
  col     values
1  c2  [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Nice one; I made several attempt to filter on actual lists, or stringified lists, but all failed.

Comment: I tried with strings, based on your method: at last this one worked (note the spaces after commas, and the mandatory single quotes inside...): `df['values'].apply(str) == "['a', 'b', 'c']"`

Comment: @Guy Thanks for your response. Though i need to filter dataframe using query().

Answer (score 1):

This is another work around.

```py
def list_equals(lst, element):
    return lst == element
    
my_df["equals"] = my_df["values"].apply(list_equals, element=['a', 'b', 'c'])

filtered_df = my_df.query("equals == True")
filtered_df = filtered_df.drop("equals", axis=1)

print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```
   col     values
1   c2  [a, b, c]
```

To produce the `values` output as list of strings you can use the `apply()` function one more time.

```py
filtered_df["values"] = filtered_df["values"].apply(str)
print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```
  col           values
1  c2  ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Nice; it seems the original problem comes from the way pandas stores lists; based on your approach, I tried `df['clone'] = [[1,2,3]]*3` then `df[df['values'] == df['clone']]` which returned the 1st row as expected.